# Join optimization between Temporary table (Memory Engine) and large physical table (1.7GB myisam)

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I am having an optimization problem with queries on a large physical table (1.7GB for 23Million rows), let's call it p_table.

I need to select thousands of rows using the primary index of the p_table. My first attempt was with an IN query using the primary index so something like

```
SELECT * FROM p_table WHERE primary_key IN (111,222,333,[... 60.000 more]).
```

Since the query was incredibly slow (50-60secs) I decided to optimize it by adding all the primary keys into a temporary table with Memory Engine and then join as follows

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table (primary_key BIGINT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=Memory;
INSERT IGNORE INTO t_table VALUES(111),(222),(333),[thousandsmore];
SELECT p.* FROM p_table AS p FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) INNER JOIN tmp_table AS t  FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)  ON t.primary_key = g.primary_key;
```

This solution speed up the query of x4 but still results in a lot of load on the server and roughly 10-20secs per query (depending on the size of the temporary table).

The EXPLAIN of the query shows that it is not using indexes even if I forced them.

```
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["select_type"]=>
  string(6) "SIMPLE"
  ["table"]=>
  string(1) "t"
  ["type"]=>
  string(3) "ALL"
  ["possible_keys"]=>
  string(7) "PRIMARY"
  ["key"]=>
  NULL
  ["key_len"]=>
  NULL
  ["ref"]=>
  NULL
  ["rows"]=>
  string(4) "64320"
  ["Extra"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

Unfortunately the whole database is more than 50GB, meaning I can not afford a full in-memory database and the large tables like p_table rely on disk I/O.

Do you have any suggestion on how to optimize the process? Also any hint on why the indexes are not being used (or more likely not shown by the EXPLAIN)?

Server Info: 
Debian 8.6
Mysql 5.5.53
8GB Ram
SSD Disks in Raid0 (it's one of the Slaves, Raid10 on the Master)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Why the index isn't used

The reason that mysql doesn't use an index here on table t is because that's completely unnecessary. You do not have a filter on your temporary table (aliased t) So you are joining every single row in your temporary table against p. There's nothing to be gained by using an index here.

From the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> To find the rows matching a WHERE clause quickly.
>
> To eliminate rows from consideration. If there is a choice between
>   multiple indexes, MySQL normally uses the index that finds the
>   smallest number of rows (the most selective index).

it doesn't fit any of the major criteria or some of the other criteria listed above. However your primary key is a covering index so mysql does have the choice of using the index instead of referring to the rows. However this doesn't lead to any particular advantage. Hence the decision not to use the index.

I would infact advice you to drop the index on the temporary table. That might even speed things up a bit because the inserting the 60,000 rows into that table would happen faster.

### Things that you can try

See if it's possible to partition your data. For example is there some pattern to the ids that you are inserting into the temporary table? See if you can partition based on that pattern

Increase memory on the server.

Use a faster hard drive or stripe the data across multiple hard drives.

switch to an RDBMS that can execute the same query in parallel on multiple CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding the indexes. Any tip on speeding up the process? The insert is blazing fast, 0.00001s so even dropping the index doesn't affect the overall performances. 

Do you think there's any other method for reaching a better select performance?

Comment: Thanks but none of the proposed solutions is currently viable. I am looking for an optimization on the Mysql Level.

Comment: Striping:  Since the work is done in a single thread, striping provides no benefit.

Comment: Parallelism won't help if you are I/O bound.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato you asked for solutions we provided, what's viable or not viable to you were not part of the conditions stipulated.

Comment: The disk requests will still be done serially, and (I think) one block will be used before requesting the next.

Comment: @RickJames Disk reads are still serial yes but the through put of the data reads are approximately double that with a non striped hard disk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0

Comment: When there are multiple connections hitting the disk, I agree that striping speeds up the system.  But I contend that each thread is not helped.

Comment: it is helped @RickJames this is standard practice for decades. It works because each thread reads the data 2x faster as explained at that link

Answer (score 1):

**What is happening**

Let me explain how MyISAM indexing works in *this* case.  There are two structures:

- The data is in a plain file (the .MYD).
- Each index (`PRIMARY KEY` or secondary key) is in a BTree structure (in the .MYI file) for that index.

The `IN( long list )` would drill down the BTree 60K times.  Each time, it will find at the bottom the offset into the .MYD file.  Then it will do a random fetch from the .MYD file.  This is *potentially* two disk hits per row fetched.  (I am assuming the non-leaf nodes of the BTree are quickly cached, so don't count.)

Each of those disk hits *might* be avoided due to caching.

- If the index is smaller than `key_buffer_size`, then possibly the BTree looks won't have to hit the disk every time.
- To fetch the data, it will ask to OS to read the data from the .MYD and let the OS cache it in whatever spare room there is.  Also, depending on how scattered the rows are, the "caching" may not help much.

Since these two cache areas are separate, and vie for RAM, I recommend 20% of RAM for the key_buffer, leaving most of RAM for data caching.  (Not knowing your details, I can't say whether 20% is optimal for *your* case.)

When you added the `MEMORY` table, you slowed it down by first walking through the memory table to find which ids to look up instead of having them directly in the query.  But, you say it went faster?  That is probably due to caching changes from one test to the next.

Also the MEMORY table took RAM away from the other caches, without providing any benefit.

**A partial solution**

There *is* a way to speed up the query.  Let me explain a little about InnoDB and its `PRIMARY KEY`.  The PK is "clustered" with the data and the two things are in the same BTree on disk (then cached in the innodb_buffer_pool).  So there is only one *potential* disk hit per row.  So...

```
ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB;
shrink key_buffer_size and raise innodb_buffer_pool_size
SELECT ... IN ( 60K values )
```

You will still be at the mercy of disk speed, but it should be faster.

**Other**

SSDs would be faster than spinning drives.

Neither `PARTITIONIng` nor 'striping' nor the Temporary table nor parallelism will help (in this case).

If you don't need the huge range of `BIGINT` (which takes 8 bytes), switch to `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes, 0..4 billion) or `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (0..16M).  This will shrink most things, thereby making them more cacheable, hence less I/O, hence faster.

Comment: Hi Rick,

Many thanks for your suggestions. The disks are already SSD (I'm on Digital Ocean). Will definitely trying going from bigint to something smaller if possible (need to check my max id). Will follow up with results

Comment: Unfortunately my highest key is "4547505810" therefore it's a bit above the INT and can not use it, need to stick with BIGINT.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: And `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'p_table';`

Comment: Please find below

`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'gender_1' \G

Engine: MyISAM
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Dynamic
           Rows: 23620723
 Avg_row_length: 32
    Data_length: 770509332
Max_data_length: 281474976710655
   Index_length: 1120541696
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2017-01-07 22:21:26
    Update_time: 2017-02-01 16:52:21
     Check_time: 2017-01-12 22:09:43
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `tmp_gender` (
  `external_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`external_user_id`)
) ENGINE=Memory DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Comment: What do you do with the 60K rows returned?  That's an awfully large resultset.

Comment: I do some operations on that (sums, max, mins, order them, group) and create a view table with the resulting data.

Comment: Could MySQL do the sums, etc?  It would probably be faster, since you are not having to shovel the data over the network.  Also, if subtotals can be created incrementally, you can get even more speedup.  See [_Summary Tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

Comment: The calculations are quite complex, to do them in mysql I'd need to do several GROUP BY, MAX and SUM that I fear would be even slower. Will give Summary tables a look and will let you  know. Many thanks